# Would sound intensity weaken or not in 1D space air with perfect elastic collision?

Tags: waves, conservation-laws, acoustics

Let's assume 2 things.

- we got 1D space of air
- we got perfect elastic collisions.

While I talk, would the intensity created at my mouth be the same at the receiver? If the answer is yes, I don't understand. Let me explain why. In the perfectly elastic collision, in order for the intensity be the same at receiver, one thing should happen. Each particle should give its whole kinetic energy to the next particle while colliding it. Otherwise, if bounce off happens, next particle which was at rest before collision wouldn't have the same energy then the cycle repeats and 3rd particle wouldn't have the same KE as 2nd one, gradually decreasing each particle's energy. So why would it be correct that intensity still would be the same at the receiver in these conditions ? Maybe, I'm misunderstanding the definition of intensity. If you say that with these conditions, particle would transfer all its KE to the next one and so on, I would ask: why..

Comment: A physical example of that would be Newton's cradle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_cradle. That is not how sound transfer in gases works, though. In reality all molecules are in motion all the time and sound is a small change in the average motion of many molecules. The thermodynamics of this process predicts that sound does not pass through gases and liquids without attenuation, which is exactly what we are observing. Thankfully the attenuation for wavelengths much larger than the average molecular distance is small.

Comment: @FlatterMann Though, nowhere in any definition of perfectly elastic collision, does it say that energy fully transfers from one to the next. You are assuming that particle 1 will give the whole of its KE to particle 2 but this is not what might happen in terms of 1D space. Why do you assume this

Comment: I was simply giving you an example of a system that does behave the way you mention. I also said that gas molecules do not behave that way and that you need to use a thermodynamics description to model sound in gases and liquids. So, no, I do not assume that gases are behaving this way because they don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is some confusion about what an elastic collision is

Your confusion comes from a misunderstanding of what an elastic collision means. I understand your confusion. The issue here is that you think that a rubber ball has elastic collisions, it does not, it actually experiences inelastic collisions. (This deserves it's own question, and it is extremely stupid... like many things in science).

### What occurs in an elastic collision

In an elastic collision between A and B. As this is 1D space all of A's kinetic energy is directed at B therefore all of A's kinetic energy is transferred to B. and all of B's kinetic energy is transferred to A.

What does this mean?

If B was stationary with 0 joules of kinetic energy, and A was moving with 1000 joules of kinetic energy, after the collision, B will have 1000 joules of kinetic energy, and A will have 0 Joules of kinetic energy.

Therefore B will be moving, and A will be stationary.

#### multi dimensional space

In 2d/3d space, most collisions involves vectors that won't transfer 100% of energy from A to B... This is because the only energy that is transferred is the energy that is pointed at B. All energy that is perpendicular to B is not transferred. So in non 1d space, when A collides with B. All of A's KE directed to B is transferred to B, and all of B's energy that is directed A is transferred A. Any energy perpendicular to A/B remains with A/B and is not transferred.

Comment: “ In an elastic collision between A and B. all of A's kinetic energy is transferred to B. and all of B's kinetic energy is transferred to A.” this definition is not stated on wikipedia. The only thing it mentions is kinetic energy of the system is conserved. This conservation does not imply your logic. But are you saying that in order for your statement to be correct, there should also be collision with zero angle ? In which case your statement becomes NOT correct

Comment: I think your statement is only correct when collision is with zero angle(straight hitting) and KE is conserved. If these 2 assumptions are not true, your statement becomes invalid

Comment: @Chemistry Yes, this is true it only applies for a straight collision.. in a 1d space all collisions have a zero angle collision.

Answer (score 5):

Consider a Newton's cradle.

[image]

Now pull back the left-most ball and let it swing into the other four. What happens? The left-most ball sticks to the middle three and the right-most ball swings out to the right. This is because Newton's cradles are designed to be as close to perfectly elastic as possible.

How the energy is distributed in any collision depends on how elastic the system is.

1. Perfectly elastic - All of the energy goes to the ball on the far right.
2. Perfectly inelastic - All of the balls stick together, and slowly swing to the right
3. Somewhere in-between - Some of the energy goes into each ball. The level of elasticity will determine the direction and speed of travel for each ball.

Now let's bring this back to sound. Realistically, sound is **not** a perfectly elastic collision. However, if we imagine some hypothetical medium in which it is perfectly elastic (and confine ourselves to 1D), all of the energy from the source will be passed along to the receiver at the far end. Just like an idealized Newton's cradle.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Though, nowhere in any definition of perfectly elastic collision, does it say that energy fully transfers from one to the next. You are assuming that particle 1 will give the whole of its KE to particle 2 but this is not what might happen in terms of 1D space. Why do you assume this ?

Comment: If we're assuming a homogenous medium (i.e. every particle is identical), then a perfectly elastic collision will transfer all energy to the second mass in a collision. [Example gif](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Elastischer_sto%C3%9F.gif)

Comment: @Chemistry Billiard balls exhibit this behavior (and have close to perfectly elastic collisions. If you hit a billiard ball straight onto a stationary billiard ball all of the first ball's energy transfers to the second ball. [See this video](https://youtu.be/4v2RHtBTbj8?t=3)

Comment: A better question... Is why would the particle bounce away? In a perfectly elastic collision all of the energy of A is transferred to B. And all of B's energy is transferred to A. If B is stationary then it has no kinetic energy. Therefore after A collides with B. B has A's kinetic energy and A has B's kinetic energy. As B was not moving, A stops moving.

Comment: @Questor well, I have played it and there're cases where cue ball bounces off with some angle.

Comment: @Chemisty you need to hit the ball perfectly straight on (or close to perfectly straight on) with no spin. Back spin will cause your ball to roll away, forward spin will cause the ball to continue forward as it

Comment: @Chemistry That's because they struck off-center. In a sound wavefront, we're considering average interactions between particles. Yes, some will strike each other off-center, but as many as strike "too-left" will probably strike "too-right".

Comment: @Questor you mean head-on collision right ? Straight hitting

Comment: So for me to understand the term, what do we call “perfect” exactly in elastic collision ? Is it head on collision only ?

Comment: @Chemistry, No, it is possible to have perfectly elastic collisions that are not head on... But in a 1d space all collisions are exactly head on. This would be easier with a notepad, some paper... A pool table, etc...

Comment: Draw a 90* triangle with one line perpendicular to the direction that B is traveling, that is the direction that A will travel after hitting B, and that is the energy of the collision that was perpendicular to B and is therefore not transferred to A.

Comment: Right. If the collision isn't head-on, then it's impossible for all of the kinetic energy to transfer. Consider the conservation of momentum. Since the struck particle won't be traveling at the same angle as the original particle, the original particle must retain some momentum such that the momenta of the two particles sum to equal the momenta of the original particle prior to the impact. That being said, your described situation was 1D, so all collisions are head-on.

Comment: Perhaps, in your answer, you should note that the exact transfer of energy would only occur in 1D space

Comment: @Questor I believe you are mistaken here. Consider the conservation of momentum.

Comment: Can you guys describe then what we call perfect then ? I guess when KE is conserved 100% ?

Comment: @Chemistry Yes, the key part of a perfectly elastic collision is that KE is entirely conserved.

Comment: Thanks to both of you so much. I think I got last question remaining here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/766599/why-energy-spread-between-different-surface-areas-are-the-same-with-sound-waves i know it is too much text but without describing bit by bit, we would end up with lots of understanding. Would appreciate so much if you could try to give your opinions on thet

Comment: @Questor Kinetic energy is a scalar quantity, not a vector. And no, you can't just assume that A's new direction of travel will be perpendicular to B's direction of travel. The angle is [primarily] determined by the impact parameter, masses, and degree of elasticity of the collision. [Scattering image](https://i.imgur.com/2H1pvee.png)

Comment: @Logan J. Fisher... Assuming a perfectly elastic collision, with point masses of negligible radii. Then you can. Also, It works well enough in the real world for billiards. But you are right about the kinetic energy... The velocity assuming a perfect collision will be such that A^2 + B ^2 = Aorig^2. Which not surprisingly is the hypotenouse created of the triangle of A/B's velocities..